# Want blessing of civil marriage

Tags: marriage

I was married 14 May 2019 to another catholic.  He was divorced 19 yrs ago and was not married in the church.  I am a widow who was divorced previously, never married in a Catholic Church.

Answer (score 1):

If neither of your exes is alive approach your Priest about a convalidation.

If either of them are still alive then you will need to enquire about an annulment. This may be a simple process.

As far as I can tell you are both Catholics who never married in the Church. If so and you had been baptized Catholic when you married your ex the Catholic Church does not see that as valid unless you had a dispensation.

If your previous marriages are found null then you can have your marriage convalidated.